# image-set in IE

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

I know that `image-set` is not supported by any internet explorer versions but is there any fallback to it? I have set a background image on an element like below:

`background: -webkit-image-set( url('image') 1x, url('path/to/image-2x') 2x );`

This works as expected and it loads the retina and non-retina versions of the image on other browsers. But this doesn't load any image on IE so I am wondering if there is any way to add a fallback image that will load in IE.

Comment: Just define a `background` *before* it. Webkit will accept the second value (last defined one) and IE will use the first value (because the second is "invalid").

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol good call. Thanks